# Validate subtitles file using vlcj (Java)

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, subtitle, vlcj

I am using an instance of vlcj `DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer` to play video. When adding subtitles to the video I want to see if the subtitle file is valid, and throw an Exception if it is not. This is my code:

```
File subtitlesFile = new File("subs.srt");
player.setSubTitleFile(subTitleFile);
```

The method `setSubTitleFile(File subTitleFile)` doesn't have a return value, but looking into its implementation I can see that it passes the call to libvlc, calling `libvlc_video_subtitle_file(libvlc_media_player_t p_mi, String psz_subtitle)`, which returns `1` or `0` depending on if the subtitles have been added successfully or not. So I inherited from `DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer` and wrote my own version of that method:

```
public void setSubTitleFile(String subTitleFileName) {
    final int status = libvlc.libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file(mediaPlayerInstance(), subTitleFileName);
    System.out.println(status);
    // throw Exception if status is false
}
```

Surprisingly this always gives me status `1`, which means success. Even if I am passing an empty text file. Is this a bug? I really do not want to parse the subtitle file manually beforehand. Using the native VLC Player, I am getting an error as expected if the subtitles are invalid. Anything I could do here?

**EDIT:**
This is a screenshot from the native VLC player when adding an empty SRT file during play.
[VLC subtitles file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec5kC.png)

Comment: I just spotted that libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file has been removed from VLC 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, LibVLC/VLC is not parsing the subtitle file when you call libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file. All it is basically doing is setting a string value on some native structure that will be used later. So, you get a status of "success" because that call did its job of setting that string value.

Therefore, you will only know if the subtitle file is valid when VLC starts playing your media and it attempts to load the file at that point. Even then, I do not think you will get a specific error message - there will simply be an absence of a subtitle track.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, caprica! I have added a screenshot from the native VLC player that shows the error message I am getting when adding an invalid (in this case - empty) subtitles file. The player was already playing at that time.

So as you can see, it doesn't just ignore showing subtitles, but it is giving me an error. Do you think VLC is parsing the file during runtime? Would mean I would have to do the same on my own :(

Comment: LibVLC is different to VLC is about as much as I can say really.

Comment: I have been testing this some more, the only thing I see regarding an invalid subtitle file is a message in the native VLC log when it attempts to parse the file - and this only happens when the video is actually playing, not when you set the file. no error makes it back to the Java layer unfortunately.

Comment: It may be possible to explicitly force the media to be parsed after you set your sub-title file and get some sort of feedback, I will update my answer if I can find a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! Curious how this will turn out

Comment: I've now done some work with the new API in LibVLC 3 and unfortunately nothing has changed, basically AFAICT you can not parse the subtitle file and get an error indicator if there's a problem.